# Ansible skipping when condition is true

Tags: ansible

I want to format a disk if it's not found to be mounted. To do that I have the following tasks:

```
- name: Check if drives are already mounted
  shell: df | grep "{{item.drive}}" | wc -l
  with_items: "{{disks}}"
  register: disks_checked
  changed_when: False

- name: output debug
  debug: var=disks_checked

- name: Make filesystem
  become: yes
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    dev: "{{item.item.drive}}"
    opts: -m 0 -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard"
  when: "item.stdout == 0"
  with_items: '{{disks_checked.results}}'
```

This is the playbook run:

```
TASK [install-cassandra : Check if drives are already mounted] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.142.0.3] => (item={u'directory': u'/var/lib/mysql', u'mount_point': u'/mnt/disks', u'drive': u'/dev/sdb'})
TASK [install-cassandra : output debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.142.0.3] => {
    "disks_checked": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
                "_ansible_item_label": {
                    "directory": "/var/lib/mysql", 
                    "drive": "/dev/sdb", 
                    "mount_point": "/mnt/disks"
                }, 
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                "changed": false, 
                "cmd": "df | grep \"/dev/sdb\" | wc -l", 
                "delta": "0:00:00.005613", 
                "end": "2019-03-07 09:48:50.293829", 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "df | grep \"/dev/sdb\" | wc -l", 
                        "_uses_shell": true, 
                        "argv": null, 
                        "chdir": null, 
                        "creates": null, 
                        "executable": null, 
                        "removes": null, 
                        "stdin": null, 
                        "warn": true
                    }
                }, 
                "item": {
                    "directory": "/var/lib/mysql", 
                    "drive": "/dev/sdb", 
                    "mount_point": "/mnt/disks"
                }, 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2019-03-07 09:48:50.288216", 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stderr_lines": [], 
                "stdout": "0", 
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "0"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

TASK [install-cassandra : Make filesystem] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [10.142.0.3] => (item={'_ansible_parsed': True, 'stderr_lines': [], u'changed': False, u'stdout': u'0', '_ansible_item_result': True, u'delta': u'0:00:00.005613', 'stdout_lines': [u'
0'], '_ansible_item_label': {u'directory': u'/var/lib/mysql', u'mount_point': u'/mnt/disks', u'drive': u'/dev/sdb'}, u'end': u'2019-03-07 09:48:50.293829', '_ansible_no_log': False, 'failed': 
False, u'cmd': u'df | grep "/dev/sdb" | wc -l', 'item': {u'directory': u'/var/lib/mysql', u'mount_point': u'/mnt/disks', u'drive': u'/dev/sdb'}, u'stderr': u'', u'rc': 0, u'invocation': {u'mod
ule_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'df | grep "/dev/sdb" | wc -l', u'removes': None, u'argv': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None, u'stdi
n': None}}, u'start': u'2019-03-07 09:48:50.288216', '_ansible_ignore_errors': None})
```

As you can see, the stdout is "0", but when evaluating the condition `when: "item.stdout == 0"` in the last task, it skips as if the condition was false.
If I change the condition to `when: "item.stdout == '0'"`, then it gets weirder with this error for the last task:

```
TASK [install-cassandra : Make filesystem] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [10.142.0.3] (...) "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.142.0.3 closed.\r\n"(...)
```

Why is the condition not being evaluated as expected? And why does it break the connection in the 2nd case?

Comment: Have you tested whether the "Make filesystem" task works if you put in the drive manually? On my test (ansible version 2.7.5) with a generic debug your second conditional worked. You can remove the "" around the conditional btw.

Comment: @CERN_Fan thanks, check my answer to the question... -_-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as CERN_Fan pointed out, the 2nd solution should work... Problem was that quote at the end of the `opts` line... I can't believe I lost 2 hours looking for the issue in other places.

I'm keeping the answer and question because the error (connection closed) was so unrelated to the problem, and someone else might bump into this.